# Is there a "Volume Select" equivalent in Blender?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, modifiers, geometry

3D Studio has a modifier called "Volume Select" that allows using an element's geometry as a sort of selection force field that influences elements in its path. It can be used to transform many at once, as illustrated below.

[image]

Is there a way to do this in Blender? If not a modifier, maybe a script? I'm trying to animate a block of cubes that shrink and grow in a pattern and something like volume selecting would help a lot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Animation Nodes can be used here. The *Find Nearest Surface Point* node is used to compute the distance between every element and its closest surface point, the distance is then used as the scale of the elements as following:

[image: Node Tree]

Evaluating the distance at an interpolation gives you fine control over its rate of change:

[image: Node Tree]

Answer (score 10):

In blender you can use Drivers.

1) In <kbd>N</kbd>-panel click <kbd>RMB</kbd> on scale and in context menu select Drivers -> Manually create later. Scale will be pink-colored

[image]

2) Open Graph Editor in Drivers Mode

3) Chose X Scale, remove all dots from curve and draw a new one (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to add a dot) You can perfectly align it using Active keyframe tab.

Here will be your curve, last 2 dots must have 0 Value, to make object completely invisible in long distance.

[image]

Horizontal will be distance between objects, vertical - Scale.

4) Goto Drivers Tab

5) Setup settings:

**Type** - Averaged Value

**Var type** - Distance

**Object 1 & 2** - is your current object and object-controller.

6) In <kbd>N</kbd>-panel <kbd>RMB</kbd>-click on X scale and in context menu select Copy Driver. When Paste Driver in Y and Z Scale.

7) Finally copy your objects in a grid or any pattern:

[image]

See also: For more advanced cases you can use node-based visual programing: [animation nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed step-by-step. This is similar to what I want to make, but I wonder if it can it be done with a volume. I tried your method with a cube instead of an empty, but the drivers only reacted to proximity with its origin and not its boundaries. Can nodes help with this?

Comment: @user62099 If you can describe the volume with a formula, you can instead use mathematical expressions for the driver, otherwise animation nodes is your bet. The following will probably be useful: https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/kd&bvhtree/is_inside_volume.html .

Answer (score -1):

1. If you want it as you showed it, create the mask first

[image]

2. Put the object to be animated in the hole less than 0,01 below the mask and make sure the mask's color is the same as world's

[image]

3. Animate the objects **within** the mask's boundaries

[image]

This is the **fastest**, **simplest** way and gives the desired effect. Nodes are needless complication.